# What are the manifestiontion of Purusha

Tags: vedas, vedanta, advaita, rig-veda, purusha

Which one is correct?

**Purusha 5 manifestation : Indra, Vayu, Agani, Varuna and Yama**

[image: Rig Veda Purusha manifestation]

**Purusha 7 manifestation : Indra, Shakti, Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva, Shani and Yama**

[image: Purusha manifestation]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.